# PHP OOP assign value to a class variable

Tags: php, mysql, oop, variables

```
class User{
public $id, $username, $firstname, $lastname;

public function find(){
$result = blabla->query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = 1');
return $result;
}
}
```

I'm interesting in how it is possible to assign value (which come from mysql) to a class variable.

```
$user = new User();
$user->find();
echo $user->username;
echo $user->lastname;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it'd work with `SELECT *`, but you can try the [`PDO::FETCH_INTO`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php#78794):

```
class User{
    public $id, $username, $firstname, $lastname;
    public function find(){
        $result = blabla->query('SELECT id, username, firstname, lastname FROM users WHERE id = 1');
        $this = $result->fetch( PDO::FETCH_INTO );
    }
}
```

---

If it doesn't work, you can use the [`bindColumn` call with `PDO::FETCH_BOUND`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindcolumn.php) option:

```
class User{
    public $id, $username, $firstname, $lastname;
    public function find() {
        $result = blabla->query('SELECT id, username, firstname, lastname FROM users WHERE id = 1');
        $result->bindColumn( 1, $this->id );
        /* Other bindColumn calls here */
        return $result->fetch( PDO::FETCH_BOUND );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to do something like this:

```
class User{
    public $id, $username, $firstname, $lastname;
    public function find () {
        $result = blabla->query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = 1');

        $this->id = $result['id'];
        $this->username = $result['username'];
        $this->firstname = $result['firstname'];
        $this->lastname = $result['lastname'];
    }
}
```